# C# serialize decimal to xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I got a decimal property, like

`[XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "decimal")] decimal Price`

The problem is that I wanna force it to serialize always with precision of 2, but if the price is 10.50 it will be serialized to XML like `<Price>10.5</Price>`.

Theres any way to force it (without creating a new property or changing the get of this property? I'm looking for some way to do this only sending a pattern to the XmlSerializer (or the XmlElementAttribute) or any smart way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I was dealing with the same problem and found your question, then found a different answer.  Check it out.

Comment: @Jim ...... and the answer is what exactly? How about a link?

Comment: @JK I think it is the one [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2456126/255).

Comment: [How to force decimal precision in xml serialization](http://slackspace.de/articles/c-how-to-force-decimal-precision-in-xml-serialization/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add `XmlIgnore` to the actual decimal property and introduce a new property PriceAsString which returns, eh, the price as string (in 10.5**0** format).

You could of course also implement `IXmlSerializable` and do everything yourself.

However, none of these ways really rocks, and you already stated you were not going to go down this road anyway...

Answer (score 30):

I was having the opposite problem.  My decimals were serializing with 4 decimal places, even though they were all 4 zeroes.  I discovered that if I call `decimal.Round(value, 2)` then it serializes to 2 decimal places.  It would appear that the Decimal type *remembers* what you last rounded it too when it is serialized.

I was suspicious of the suggestion, but it worked that simply.  Even though the value didn't need rounding, calling Round changed how many decimal places showed up in serialization.

Comment: Nice! All I've done is when setting a value use decimal.Round with desired precision. This is the *real* answer!

Comment: I was required to output a hard coded value of '0.00' and (in VB.NET) this was the only thing that worked: Decimal.Round(0.00D, 2)

Comment: It is working because decimal stores value with floating point (i.e. 550.0000 is stored as 5500000 * 10^-4, and if you round it to 2 decimals it will bee 55000 * 10^-2), and obviously serializer just takes whatever is in and then puts decimal point depending on exponent.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a decimal with 1dp, and you try and round it to 2.

Comment: I do this: decimal.Round(value*1.00m, 2)

Answer (score 1):

I had a few `int`s that I assigned to `decimal` properties (of the object-to-serialize). They needed to be written with 2 decimals by the XML Serializer, but came out without decimals.

Assuming

```
var myInt = 3;
```

**No success:**

Setting a property that needs serialization via

```
obj.Property = decimal.Round((decimal)myInt, 2);
```

results in no decimals being written at serialization.

**Success:**

With

```
obj.Property = decimal.Parse(d.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get two decimals.

**Now I now use these extension methods at setting the properties:**

```
/// <summary>
/// For XML serialization.
/// </summary>
public static class DecimalSerializationHelper
{
    public static decimal WithTwoDecimals(this decimal d)
        => decimal.Parse(d.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    public static decimal WithTwoDecimals(this int x) => ((decimal)x).WithTwoDecimals();
}
```

so that it reads like

```
obj.Property = myInt.WithTwoDecimals();
```