# Override any XmlConverter class like Newtonsoft's JsonConverter [C#]

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

How can I implement XML similar to what I did with Json below:

I overridden JsonConverter class of Newtonsoft

```
public class DecimalFormatConverter : JsonConverter 
{ 
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) 
    { 
        writer.WriteValue(string.Format("{0:N2}", value)); 
    } 
}
```

And add attribute for Total:

```
JsonConverter(typeof(DecimalFormatConverter))] 
public decimal Total { get; set; }
```

Also, Where can I find a similar XMLConverter class to reuse? Newtonsoft only has JsonConverter

Comment: If you're talking about `XmlSerializer`, there's no direct analogue of `JsonConverter`.  One possibility is to use a surrogate type for your `decimal` property along the lines of [Most elegant xml serialization of Color structure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322461/3744182).  Another would be to [implement `IXmlSerializable`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly).  Beyond that, please [edit] your question to include a specific [mcve] that shows your precise problem.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: But if you're just looking to control the formatting for a specific decimal, you could use a surrogate property along the lines of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1118855/3744182) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1613537/3744182).